# A positive integer has $1001$ digits all of which are $1$'s. When this number is divided by $1001$ find the remainder

Tags: divisibility, repunit-numbers

A positive integer has $1001$ digits all of which are $1$'s. When this number is divided by $1001$ find the remainder.

I tried to think on it but couldn't get through. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A=111111... (1001 \text { times})$$
$$A= 10^{1000}+10^{999}+10^{998}+\cdots +10^0$$
$$A= (10^{1000}+10^{997})+(10^{999}+10^{996})+\cdots+ 
(10^4+10^1)+ (10^3+10^0)+10^2$$
Now, any number of the form $10^{m+3}+10^m (m\geq 0)$ is divisible by $1001$.
$$A=1001n+10^2$$ So the remainder is $100$.

Comment: This is incorrect, but you could get your approach to work by saying that $10^{1000}+10^{997}+10^{999}+10^{996}+10^{998}+10^{995}+10^{994}+10^{991}+...+10^4+10^1+10^3+10^0$ is divisible by $1001$, leaving remainder $10^2$,  because $10^{m+\color{red}3}+10^m$ is divisible by $1001$

Comment: @DwijRajHari Your answer is wrong.

Comment: Oops I will edit it

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I have corrected  it. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Thank You. I got it!

Comment: To much is hidden in the „...“. In the Last Version of your answer you got the Result 1, now you get 100 and the answers Look like rather similar. You should find a notation That helps to avoid the error you did.

Comment: @miracle173 the error was there because earlier I took $10^{m+2}+10^m$ to be divisible by $1001$ , whitch was wrong. It should be $10^{m+\color{red}3}+10^m$

Comment: @DwijRajHari i see now, I checked the edit history. But from you notation its not immediately  clear why not $A= (10^{1000}+10^{997})+(10^{999}+10^{996})+\cdots+ (10^4+10^1)+10^0$

Answer (score 4):

$10^3\equiv-1\bmod1001$

$10^{999}\equiv-1\bmod1001$

$10^{1001}\equiv-100\equiv901\bmod1001$

$10^{1001}-1\equiv900\bmod1001$

$\dfrac{10^{1001}-1}9\equiv100\bmod1001$

Answer (score 0):

this question can actually done in a much simpler way guys!
we know that,
1001 can perfectly divide 111111(a number with 6 one's)
so in the given number,

```
                   *there are 1001 digits in which 996(the last no. divisible by 6)
                   can be divided with no remainder.*
```

therefore the **last 5 one's (11111)** must be divided by 1001 to get the remainder.
11111/1001 gives **100** as ur answer.

and u have the way to go!!